# Where to find uwsgi.conf when uwsgi is installed in a virtualenv

Tags: uwsgi

Everywhere I find a description of uwsgi they say that the conf file can be found in /etc/uwsgi/. But I am playing with installing uwsgi in my virtualenv, so there is no such folder in /etc

Answer (score 0):

You can place the uWSGI configuration file where you want. The path is not hardcoded. What you see are mostly distribution packages conventions or sysadmin taste.

Comment: Read them multiple times before asking the question here. Docs only makes sense if you already know the content of the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no auto generated uwsgi.conf file. So you have to create your own.

It seems you have to install uwsgi both locally (in the virtualenv) and globally. Then make a uwsgi_my_app.conf file and put it in the /etc/init folder. This file should contain:

```
description "uwsgi my_app instance"
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec uwsgi --ini /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/my_app.ini
```

Then make a my_app.ini file in /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled (you also have to create this directory), with your uwsgi settings. Example:

```
[uwsgi]
uid = www-data
gid = www-data

# the virtualenv (full path)
virtualenv = path/to/venv
# Project path
chdir = path/to/my_app
# Django's wsgi file (path starting from chdir/)
wsgi-file = my_app/wsgi.py

# the socket (use the full path to be safe)
socket  = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
# ... with appropriate permissions
chmod-socket = 664

logto = path/to/logs/uwsgi.log

enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
thunder-lock = true
die-on-term = true
master = true

threads = 5
processes = 2
max-requests = 1000
buffer-size = 32768
post-buffering = 8192

# clear environment on exit
vacuum = true
```

Now you can start/stop/restart uwsgi with:

```
sudo service start uwsgi_my_app
```